# JavaFX ControlsFX CSS for RangeSlider

Tags: java, css, javafx, rangeslider, controlsfx

I have just downloaded the JavaFX ControlsFX library and am currently stuck. I'm using one of the custom components in the library, called a RangeSlider, but need to manipulate style for each thumb in CSS. I've looked all over the place but can't seem to find anything useful. Is there a way to do that? I know with regular java Slider components, this can be done:

```
.slider .thumb {
     // Style code here
 }
```

But when I use something like this for RangeSlider, nothing works. It makes sense because there's 2 sliders, but I've tried 100 combinations for what the substructure names would be to no avail.

Mission: I'm trying to change each thumbs icon and I'm also interested in changing the color that is drawn in between the 2 thumbs(currently blue).

Hopefully this is something wildly obvious, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default style class for a `RangeSlider` is `range-slider`. You can find all the style rules in the `rangeslider.css` file (on the controlsfx.jar) or on the [repository](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/7f71c7343ab93ac66abeecb79cb5149bbaeca8ca/controlsfx/src/main/resources/org/controlsfx/control/rangeslider.css?at=default).

If you want to change the thumbs, those are `StackPane` objects, you can use `-fx-shape`:

```
.range-slider .low-thumb {
    -fx-shape: "M2.998-0.07L3-1.499l2.998,4L3,6.501l-0.002-1.43l1.976-2.57L2.998-0.07z";
}
.range-slider .high-thumb {
    -fx-shape: "M5.997,5.072L5.995,6.501l-2.998-4l2.998-4l0.002,1.43l-1.976,2.57L5.997,5.072z";
}
```

This will change the range bar color:

```
.range-slider .range-bar {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

[image: rangeslider]